# FME: Connecting the output of a workflow to the input of another workflow

Tags: fme-form, workspace

> **Solved:** I've tried the advice from @Mapperz - Connecting the transformer before the Writer is writing the shp with the transformers "AttributeVreator_2 & Dissolver". 
>   Anyway, I'm still interested on my question. It is possible to connect a Writer and Reader module, that the Reader uses the output of another workflow?

`Version: FME Desktop 2014 SP3`

I have 2 separate workflows which I run one after other. This is a litte bit inefficient, therefore i want to optimize the process by  connecting the two workflows.

Workflow 1 generates a shape with lots of attributes as output.

Workflow 2 uses this output (shape) to do more operations.

**Problem:** I'm unable to link the output of Workflow 1 to the input of Workflow 2. I tried it with the Transformer "WorkspaceRunner", but it is not possible to define the right input for me.

Maybe there is antoher way to solve this problem?

[image: Workflow 1 output(left) should be the input of Workflow 2 (right)]

Comment: you do not need to write to shape and then re-load that file just use the tranformer before the shp writer and connect to your attribute creator_2/dissolver - seeing entire workspace would help.